# Override Standard Delete Action on Account Object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, delete

how can i override standard delete action on Account with a Lightning component? I use Lightning Experience and i want when user selects delete action to show a message "Delete accounts is not permitted for this org". Unfortunately, although i have overriden the New action, i cannot see any ways to override tha delete action.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot override the delete action.

You need to remove the Delete permission for Account for those Profiles which you wish to disallow from this action. (This [Trailhead project](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/protect-your-data-in-salesforce/create-new-users-and-delete-accounts) implements the reverse via Permission Sets, and hence may be useful to review).

If you need to allow the user to *attempt* to delete and then present a failure message - which I strongly urge against, it will not be user-friendly - you'll have to write an Apex trigger.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. i would have already disabled the delete permission, however i need it cause these users will need to perform merge operations on Accounts.

Comment: Hello again David, finally i did it with trigger after Delete Account by checking the id of masterRecord. So if it is from merge operation the delete occurs, otherwise it shows the error message via Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on from David's answer, would it be adequate to hide the 'Delete' button on the page layout and related list?

If not, please do vote for this idea to allow validation rules before records are deleted (which would solve your problem if it were available): https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrGiAAK

Comment: Hi Dan, and thanks for your answer! no it would not be adequate.. Actually, i have already hide it from the page layout .The problem is i cannot hide it from the List View Action! I will vote for this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved my issue the following way: Apex trigger and if it is from merge, delete occurs normally, else get this error message!

```
trigger ea_PreventDeleteAccount on Account (after delete) {
    for (Account acc: trigger.old) {
        if(acc.MasterRecordId == null){
            acc.addError('Delete Account is not allowed!');
        }
    }
}
```